# Visual Studio 2008 hanging in 64bit Windows 7

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2008, windows-7, 64-bit, freeze

I have brand new Win7 64bit machine. Visual Studio 2008 is newly installed, but has started responding more and more slowly, eventually hanging completely and occupying one (virtual) core of the machine completely. After an hour or so of increasingly slow response I close it and start again, whereupon it runs fine at first before gradually slowing down again.

Using Process Explorer I have found that the responsible *devenv.exe* thread always has a stack which looks something like this when it is pegging the processor:

```
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc0a
ntoskrnl.exe!KeAcquireSpinLockAtDpcLevel+0x732
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMutexObject+0x19f
ntoskrnl.exe!__misaligned_access+0xba4
msenv.dll!DllCanUnloadNow+0x49b31
```

with one or more `ntoskrnl.exe!__misaligned_access` and `msenv.dll!DllCanUnloadNow` lines; can anyone give me an idea of what might be going wrong? Thanks!

UPDATE:

Having started VS via the command line switch /SafeMode (thanks 0xA3), I find that without Resharper the problem seems to go away... So it looks likely to be a Resharper bug :(

Comment: Any Visual Studio extensions / add-ons installed?

Comment: Resharper 5.1, but it is not the Resharper process that hangs the CPU.

Comment: Did you start VS without Resharper? Use the /SafeMode switch and see whether the issue persists.

Comment: OK, will try this out tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

did you check all other threads in the process?  (both managed and un-managed) to see if any thread is busy or waiting in non-trivial place with stacks unlike others?  Main thread is obviously waiting, most likely on another thread of the same process - I'm curious to know what other callstacks are out there.

Comment: Which threads would be of interest? I count ~60 at any one time, though most are CreateApplicationContext and _endthreadex...

Comment: I am afraid there is no simpler or automatic way to do this other than going through every single one.  Eliminate all that look alike and pick all that have stacks involving modules from VS or 3rd party - you should end up with a couple max.